# AVPlayer can't play Vevo Youtube video

Tags: ios, youtube

I'm developing my youtube app on iOS and using AVPlayer to play video. But I don't know why my player can't play the Vevo video. Any idea for my problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the iOS Youtube Helper library for playing youtube videos.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

I don't know if you can use the AVPlayer. I've seen some examples using MPMoviePlayerController on CocoaControls, like this one: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hcyoutubeparser or this one: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/xcdyoutubevideoplayerviewcontroller

But I don't think using youtube's url directly in your player fits the ToS of the platform. So I will recommend you tu use the Youtube Helper Library if you are planning to publish your app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use AVPlayer to customize my player view with some options. I'm also using XCDYouTubeKit to parse and get url from video identifier. But the url is not possible to play by AVPlayer when it's Vevo video(regular video is ok).